# Error when trying to assign NSUInteger to dictionary literal

Tags: objective-c

I have

```
-(void)saveAsset:(NSUInteger) assetID 
{
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
  NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"asset_id": assetID};
```

but get the following error:

```
Collection element of type 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned long') is not an Objective-C object
```

How can I assign this? I have tried:

```
  NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"asset_id": [assetID integerValue]};
```

and

```
  NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"asset_id": (id)assetID};
```

but neither of them are working.

Comment: Read the documentation on what types of things an `NSDictionary` value can be.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
@(assetID)
```

or (in old syntax):

```
[NSNumber numberWithInteger:assetID]
```

You tried to assign simple value (like int, char, etc.), while expected type is obj-c object (like NSNumber).

Btw. NSInteger is target depending type, so it will be 32-bit or 64-bit integer depending on target cpu.